# How to disable showing log on terminal in latex

Tags: terminal-output

How do I disable showing all information to the terminal?

Is possible to only show errors not log,warnings etc.?

Comment: `pdflatex -interaction=batchmode`  (but you still get the startup message)

Comment: No, you can't. TeX has only one output channel, directed to STDOUT, besides the channel for writing the log file.

Comment: ... and as @egreg says  batchmode may not be what you want as it suppresses error messages as well (they also only go to the log not the terminal)